# Dynamic Variable Assignment in Azure DevOps YAML Based on Conditions

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm facing an issue with dynamically assigning variables in Azure DevOps YAML based on conditions related to the branch name. My goal is to assign specific variables that can later be utilized within tasks. However, I'm encountering problems when attempting to set the AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION variable using conditions in my YAML file.

Here's the relevant part of my YAML:

```
variables:
  BRANCH_NAME: $[replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '')]
  ${{ if eq(variables['BRANCH_NAME'], 'dev') }}:
    TF_ENVIRONMENT: dev
    AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION: xxxx
    AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: xxx
  ${{ elseif eq(variables['BRANCH_NAME'], 'staging') }}:
    TF_ENVIRONMENT: stage
    AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION: 'test'
    AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: xxxx
  ${{ elseif eq(variables['BRANCH_NAME'], 'feature/xxx') }}:
    TF_ENVIRONMENT: xxx
    AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION: xxxx
    AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: xxxx
  ${{ elseif eq(variables['BRANCH_NAME'], 'master') }}:
    TF_ENVIRONMENT: prod
    AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION: xxxxx
    AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: xxxxx

steps:
  - script:
      # ...
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION)
```

The trick with ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'dev') }} gets the job done, but it's a no-go for me because it can't handle branches with '/'.

My issue lies in the fact that the AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION variable doesn't seem to be assigned as expected. I suspect there might be an error in my condition logic or how I'm referencing the variable.
Could someone please review my YAML and provide insights into why the AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION variable isn't being assigned correctly?

Comment: Instead of doing the string replacement, you could use the `Build.SourceBranchName` which gives you just the branch name. 

As for the azure subscription issue, what is the error you are getting? What are you passing, and what is that you get? The logic is pretty straight forward, and it should just pass what you're putting in the variable. 
The only reason it would fail is that the `AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION` value is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string replacement is wrong.
Instead of `BRANCH_NAME: $[replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '')]` use `BRANCH_NAME: ${{ replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '') }}`.
Notice the replacement of `$[]` with `${{}}`.

As I mentioned in the comment, you could replace the whole string replacement expression with `BRANCH_NAME: ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName'] }}`.
`Build.SourceBranchName` gives you the branch name only. [Source here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

**Edit:**

Referencing a variable using runtime expression only works outside complex expressions such as if statement which you are using.
To make use of the variables set in the if statement, a compile time expression is needed, such as `${{ variables.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION }}`.

[Source, Conditional insertion.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried the solution you provided, but unfortunately, I am still encountering the same error message:

Job Job: Step input azureSubscription references service connection $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION) which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, please refer to the following link: https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.

Interestingly, when I manually set the value of AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION before the if-else expression and comment out the evaluation of the if-else statement, the error disappears.

Comment: Hmm, @stela could you try to output the variables you are setting and see if they are actually set. If none of the if statements are reached, then the variables will not be created at all. 

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: echo $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION)
```

It would be a good idea to have a default if statement in case no branch name is matched.

Comment: It looks like the variables are grabbing the right values when I display them in the script or the task you've given. But when I try to use these values in my task, which is the AzureCLI@2 task, things don't seem to work as expected. Any thoughts on what might be causing this hiccup?

Comment: Hmm, try referencing the `AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION` using the compile time expression. `${{ variables.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION }}`. 
The $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION) expression only works outside complex expressions such as if statements, that's why it works if you set the variable manually outside the if statement, as you previously noticed.
I'll update my answer to contain this piece of info.